# how to differentiate bitcoin-cli command when have testnet & mainnet both running

Tags: testnet

I have bitcoin testnet3, mainnet, regtest both running in the same server, I can interactive with them by curl, because the ports are different, but when comes to bitcoin-cli how can I specific the network I want interactive with?

I get below error:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest setgenerate true 101  # I want use regtest
Error: Invalid combination of -regtest and -testnet.
```

Comment: Does your `bitcoin.conf` file contain a line `testnet=1` ?

Comment: yes, for testnet testnet=1 is on

Comment: So `bitcoin-cli` is combining the options from the command line and the config file, and sees both which are in conflict with eachother.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `-rpcport` flag to bitcoin-cli to specify which node to connect to when running multiple on the same machine.